# Javafx cannot update the text for tempDisplay label

Tags: javafx

I cannot set the text for the tempDisplay label by using settext() in connectArduino method. It only can show part of the string, like the symbol "°C", just like the screen shot shows. But the string "input" can be print out actually.
Here is my controller class

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jssc.SerialPort;
import static jssc.SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class MainController {

SerialPort arduinoPort = null;
ObservableList<String> portList;
public String input;
public static double max;
public static double min;
public static String phoneNumber;
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = 
"AC935209d3c44660b4a550e3380249857a";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "42bcd28e23344404c737eb3499d2a747";
final int NUM_OF_POINT = 300;
XYChart.Series series;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboBox;

@FXML
private ToggleButton modeButton;

@FXML
private ToggleButton ledButton;

@FXML
private  Button connectButton;

@FXML
private TextArea displayArea;

@FXML
private Label tempDisplay;

@FXML
private NumberAxis xAxis;

@FXML
private NumberAxis yAxis;

@FXML
private LineChart lineChart;

@FXML
private void initialize(){
    displayArea.setEditable(false);
    detectPort();
    comboBox.setPromptText("Port List");
    comboBox.setItems(portList);
    setLineChart();
    //sendSMS();
}

private void detectPort(){
    portList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String[] serialPortNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    portList.addAll(serialPortNames);
}

private void connect(){
    disconnectArduino();
    if(connectButton.getText().equals("Connect")) {
        connectArduino(comboBox.getValue().toString());
    }
    ledButton.setSelected(false);
}

public boolean connectArduino(String port){

    displayArea.appendText("connect Arduino");
    if(port.isEmpty()){
        alert("Connect Failed!");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
        boolean success = false;
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(port);
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(
                    SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort.setEventsMask(MASK_RXCHAR);
            serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) -> {
                if (serialPortEvent.isRXCHAR()) {
                    try {
                        input = serialPort.readString(serialPortEvent
                                .getEventValue());
                        System.out.println(input);
                        if (input.contains("false")) {
                            alert("Unplugged Sensor");
                        } else {
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                String st = input + " °C";
                                tempDisplay.setText(st);
                              //  shiftSeriesData(Float.parseFloat(input));
                            });

                        }

                    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName())
                                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        alert("No Data Available");
                    }
                }
            });

            arduinoPort = serialPort;
            success = true;
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("SerialPortException: " + ex.toString());
            alert("No Data Available");
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

Here is my fxml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"     minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="627.0" prefWidth="664.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="MainController">
    <children>
        <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" createSymbols="false" layoutY="74.0"     prefHeight="343.0" prefWidth="396.0" title="Temperature of Session">

           <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis autoRanging="false" label="Time (s)" side="BOTTOM" tickUnit="100" fx:id="xAxis" upperBound="300"/>
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" autoRanging="false" label="Temperature (°C)" lowerBound="10" side="RIGHT" upperBound="50" />
        </yAxis>

    </LineChart>
    <TextArea fx:id="displayArea" editable="false" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="426.0" prefHeight="186.0" prefWidth="635.0" />
    <Label layoutX="94.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="482.0" text="Team Placeholder Themometer Interface">
        <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
        </font>
    </Label>
    <Button fx:id="connectButton" layoutX="475.0" layoutY="145.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connectPressed" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Connect">
        <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
        </font>
    </Button>
    <Button fx:id="setButton" layoutX="475.0" layoutY="241.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setPressed" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Set SMS" />
    <Label layoutX="400.0" layoutY="314.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Current Temperature" />
    <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="475.0" layoutY="94.0" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="131.0" />
    <ToggleButton fx:id="ledButton" layoutX="540.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ledPressed" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Show on LEDs" />
    <ToggleButton fx:id="modeButton" layoutX="540.0" layoutY="314.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#modePressed" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="In Fahrenheit" />
    <Label fx:id="tempDisplay" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="341.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="131.0" textFill="#e10707">
        <font>
            <Font size="32.0" />
        </font>
    </Label>
</children>
```

Screen shot for the interface

[image]

Comment: As you can see, your tempDisplay has prefWidth="131.0". It will not resize automatically, just cut the text out. Maybe use Text instead of Label, or manually resize the prefWidth or whatever suits you best.

Comment: What is the console output? Could it be that you get two inputs, the second one being empty? You may want to change the scope of `input` to be only inside the serial read callback, so you are certain it doesn't change in between reading and calling `Platform.runLater`